# How to create time string from integers

Tags: c, string, integer, char

I have the following in C:

```
char time[8];
int hour= 5;
int minute = 4;
int second = 13;
```

The output should be the following;

```
Output:
"05:04:13" //printf("%s",time);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `snprintf()` if you have it, else `sprintf()`:

```
snprintf(time, sizeof time, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
```

Note that your buffer is too small, you need two + two + two for the digits, plus two more for the colons, plus a final character for the termination. So it should be at least `char time[9];`. If you use `snprintf()`, it will properly truncate and not cause a buffer overrun, but `sprintf()` will fail.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that sprintf could have more then 3 parameters.

Comment: @dare2k It's a different function, note the *n* in the beginning. `snprintf()` is different from `sprintf()`. Of course, both can accept any number of parameters, since they use variable-arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
sprintf(time, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
printf("%s",time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative (longer) way of achieving the same results by converting `int` to `char` strings.

```
int hour= 5;
int minute = 4;
int second = 13;
char hr[3];
char min[3];
char sec[3];

itoa(hour, hr, 10);
itoa(minute, min, 10);
itoa(second, sec, 10);

printf("%s:%s:%s", hr,min,sec);
```

But just to make it clear that [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) function is `is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.`

Comment: I am using gnu and having problem with itoa.